# Search in the PATH for commands starting with a particular letter

Tags: shell-script, shell, find, path

Which command could I use list all commands that start with the letter `g`? Let's assume I can't use `bash` completion, and that a script must be written.

Comment: Welcome new user, some question cause you get negative reputation, before any ask, read the following manual to avoid nagative reputation: http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: Also for avoiding any negative reputation for any answer, read the following link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/answering

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to go through all directories listed in `PATH` and run a `find` to search for the pattern, in this case, binaries starting with the letter *'g'*. Just run:

```
for i in $(echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n")
do
  find ${i} -iname "g*" 2> /dev/null
done
```

It's important to mention that some directories might not have one single file matching the regex, so you must discard the error output with `2> /dev/null`.

This approach can be useful for many other situations, like searching for a static or dynamic library for example.

Comment: The `echo $PATH` bit would not work if you would need to preserve whitespace in any of the path elements, or avoid globbing. It may under some circumstances also interpret backslashes specially.  The `find` command would additionally invoke splitting and globbing (again) on `$i`, and it would return any name starting with `g`, executable or not, anywhere below the given directory (these may not be "commands").

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a single simple command you could use to do this in `bash`, but it probably violates the requirement of "not using `bash` completion".  I have included this at the end of this answer nonetheless.  Instead I'll be using a couple of loops to solve this.

Assuming you'd want to find all executable external commands starting with the letter `g` in any of the directories listed in your `$PATH`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

IFS=:; set -f; set -- $PATH; set +f
for dirpath do
    for pathname in "$dirpath"/g*; do
        if [ -x "$pathname" ]; then
            printf 'Executable: %s (%s)\n' "${pathname##*/}" "$pathname"
        fi
    done
done
```

This first sets the positional parameters to the list of directories held in your `PATH` variable.  It does this by setting `IFS` to `:`.  This means that when we use `$PATH` unquoted, its value will be split on the `:`-characters in the string.  To use the variable unquoted safely, we also use `set -f` to turn off globbing temporarily, just in case any part of the string can be interpreted as a filename globbing pattern.  We enabled globbing again with `set +f` because we need it later.

Once we have set the positional parameters to the list of directory paths, we iterate over these.  In each iteration, we get the pathnames of any files that start with the letter `g` in that directory and test each one to see whether it 1) exists, and 2) is executable (the `-x` test does both of these things).  If it is executable, we output its name and its full pathname.

Note that this is restricting the question to only cover external executable commands in the current `$PATH`.  It will not find aliases or shell functions. Utilities that are only available as built-in utilities will also not be considered.

With a shell that understands `${variable//pattern/word}` for replacing a pattern with a string anywhere in a variable's value, and with a `find` that knows `-maxdepth` and `-executable` (kudos to [isaac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/265604/isaac) for mentioning this approach elsewhere):

```
(
    set -f
    find -H -- ${PATH//:/ } -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'g*' -executable
)
```

This would turn off globbing for the `find` command, then search each of the directories listed in `$PATH` for any name starting with `g` that corresponds to an executable file.  This would find executable by the current user only.  Use `-perm -o+x` instead of `-executable` to test whether the executable bit is set for "others" instead.

The `-H` option for `find` will make it resolve symbolic links given on the command line (i.e. the search paths), but not the ones found while traversing the paths.

---

The above was a generic `/bin/sh` solution.  If you are allowed to use special `bash` commands, you may generate a list of all external command, shell functions and aliases, that start with the letter `g` with

```
compgen -c g
```

To include built-in commands, use

```
compgen -bc g
```

... but this may count as "using `bash` completion".

The `compgen` built-in command is documented in the `bash(1)` manual.