# Search for commands (for the present user) starting with some particular letter

Tags: shell, find, path

Which command could I use list all commands that start with the letter g?

I have read the [question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157887/search-in-the-path-for-commands-starting-with-a-particular-letter) but I seek for an answer without arbitrary limits. If shell completion gives an answer, it should be included.

However, if there is an answer which runs in many/most shells that would be preferable.

Would:

```
( set -f; find ${PATH//:/ } -type f -maxdepth 1 -executable )
```

be a suitable answer? Not all `find`s have all those options, correct?

Comment: Related: [Search for command with wildcard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434884/search-for-command-with-wildcard)

Comment: If you are interested in the `bash` shell specifically, then [my answer to that question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447938/116858) covers that. Note that tab completion is not a standard feature and even though most shells implement it, the hooks (commands) that the shell provides to manipulate it will be different. Narrowing the question down to a particular shell would therefore be helpful.

Comment: @Kusalananda Then please write an answer (for bash) and comment about the find command on the OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find` command that you show,

```sh
( set -f; find ${PATH//:/ } -type f -maxdepth 1 -executable )
```

would be suitable for most circumstances, given that it was run on a machine with GNU `find` installed, which implements both `-maxdepth` and `-executable` (and I *really* don't want to try to craft an equivalent test for `-executable` using standard `find` predicates). It also requires `bash` for doing the parameter substitution on the value of `PATH`, changing each `:` into a space (this could also be done through setting `IFS=:` and using the variable unquoted as is, removing the requirement for `bash`).

In [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447938/116858) to a similar question, I also I protected the `find` command from interpreting the search paths as potential options with `--`. The command shown here is using the approach with `IFS`, and is also slightly tweaked after doing some proper testing of it:

```bash
(
    set -f; IFS=:
    find -L -- $PATH -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -executable
)
```

The `! -type d` ensures that executable symbolic links, but not directories, are also found.  The `-L` option makes sure that meta data relating to found symbolic links are taken from the thing that the link is pointing to (this prevents finding symbolic links to accessible, i.e. executable, subdirectories).

Testing this against `compgen -c` in `bash` shows that `compgen -c` will produce a list of commands overlapping with the result from the above `find` command, and that any additional commands that `compgen -c` finds is limited to built-in commands that have no external implementation.

Obviously, to limit this to commands starting with the character `g`, you would also want to use `-name 'g*'` (`compgen -c g` in `bash`).

A shell that provides tab completion of commands, like `bash`, may expose commands for interacting with this mechanism. These commands will unlikely be portable between shells, and possibly not even between versions of the same shell.  The `find` command above, seems to provide a fairly good approximation to what a tab completion of *external* commands would give you though, and only relies on the presence af GNU `find`.

For a rewrite of the `-executable` predicate using standard `find` predicates, see [Stéphane Chazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88591/116858) to another question (which deals with `-readable`, but the solution is analogous to `-executable`).

The `-maxdepth` predicate is also non-standard, but are more commonly implemented across various variations of the `find` command.